# Duplicate case error during implementation of two dialogs

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I am trying to implement both the date picker and time picker. However, when I try to define two cases in the following code, I get an error that there is a duplicate case.

Code:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
{
    switch(id){
    case ID_DATEPICKER:
        Toast.makeText(SendMail.this, "Select Appointment Date", 
                                                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, myDateSetListener, myYear, myMonth, myDay);
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        Toast.makeText(SendMail.this, "Select Appointment Time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return new TimePickerDialog(this,mTimeSetListener, 0, 0, false);
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

What is the solution?

Comment: sorry about not pasting the code properly... plz forgive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure ID_DATEPICKER and TIME_DIALOG_ID do not have the same int value.